# Divide a large image into two non overlapping images whose union is the large image

Tags: c++, image-processing

Given a large image composed of smaller images stored as a matrix. I need to find out a boundary dividing the large image into two parts(not necessarily equal but preferably nearly equal) without cutting past a smaller image.

Each small image is represented by a single integer in the larger image matrix.
Ex:

```
1 1 2 2 2 
1 1 2 2 2
3 3 3 4 4
3 3 3 4 4
```

is the large image matrix composed of 4 small images.
I need to find one such boundary to separate it into two smaller images such that their sizes don't differ by a very large amount.

This is my solution:
1. Start from considering the 1st row.
2. Using binary search find the start of a boundary. In above example it will be like

```
  1 1 | 2 2 2 
  1 1   2 2 2
  3 3   3 4 4
  3 3   3 4 4
```

3.Proceed down until the dividing line doesn't intersect an image. If end of large image is reached then stop.

```
  1 1 | 2 2 2 
  1 1 | 2 2 2
  3 3   3 4 4
  3 3   3 4 4
```

4.Again do step 1,2,3 considering the remaining rows and make horizontal line from old line to new division line.

```
  1 1 | 2 2 2 
  1 1 | 2 2 2
       --
  3 3   3 4 4
  3 3   3 4 4
```

```
  1 1 |  2  2 2 
  1 1 |  2  2 2
      -----
  3 3   3 | 4 4
  3 3   3 | 4 4
```

End of large image...Stop.

Of-course if no vertical line can be found in step 2. We can look for a horizontal line first in a similar way like in the case of:

```
  1 1 1 1 1
  1 1 1 1 1
  --
  3 3 3 2 2
  3 3 3 2 2
```

and then proceed.

How can I improve on this solution? 
Are there better solutions and will my algorithm fail anytime?
I will be coding in C++. A heuristic/ greedy solution will be nice as well.

Comment: Two things I can think of would be, since you want the halves as close to equal as possible, start in the middle, and work your way out to the edges, and alternate between horizontal and vertical rather than exhausting horizontal before even starting with vertical. Both make the indexing a little more complex, but it's often the case that faster code is somewhat more complex than the naive straight-forward approach. Also, I think your step 4 is unnecessary - at least if you only want straight-line solutions. If multi-segment solutions are ok, then that's fine...

Answer (score 0):

If the image is somehow big enough to make sense then you could get local differences to guide your boundaries selection.
Here is an example implemented in MATLAB for simplicity but you will get the picture:
suppose we create an image similar to the one you defined:

```
img = [ ones(20,20), 2*ones(20,30); ones(10,20), 2*ones(10,30); 3*ones(20,30), 4*ones(20,20)]
```

This command creates an image 50x50, having a 20x30 sub-image 1, a 30x30 sub-image 2, a 30x20 sub-image 3 and a 20x20 sub-image 4, as depicted graphically bellow:
[image: color-coded image]
Ideally you would like to get the boundaries between these "trays" representing the values 1 to 4. One way to do so is to shift the image one pixel left/right and one pixel top/bottom and subtract it with the original. This will produce another image with values only in the boundary positions.
See for example in MATLAB:

```
mask=((img-shift(img,1) + img-shift(img',1)')~=0);
```

This will create a mask by adding the difference of the right-shifted image and the original with the difference of the bottom-shifted image and the original, and, finally, by comparing the result with zero (zero values will be all pixel values except in boundaries). Function shift just shifts values of a matrix right or left. There is no need to put the code here since I just want to show the concept.
So you will end-up with the following mask image:
[image: mask image]
This mask has been cropped one pixel at the right and bottom since the previous subtractions produces a border that is not needed.
In this image, true values (white pixels) are on the last pixel of the previous image, i.e. image 1 ends at the 1st boundary and image 2 begins at the next pixel, so image 1 is bounded by x=20 and y=30, and so on for the other sub-images.